# How does this specific section of code work?

Tags: python

```
def add_info_extractor(self, ie):
    """Add an InfoExtractor object to the end of the list."""
    self._ies.append(ie)
    if not isinstance(ie, type):
        self._ies_instances[ie.ie_key()] = ie
        ie.set_downloader(self)

def get_info_extractor(self, ie_key):
    """
    Get an instance of an IE with name ie_key, it will try to get one from
    the _ies list, if there's no instance it will create a new one and add
    it to the extractor list.
    """
    ie = self._ies_instances.get(ie_key)
    if ie is None:
        ie = get_info_extractor(ie_key)()
        self.add_info_extractor(ie)
    return ie
```

The following is taken from a popular python repo, the youtube-dl. In an effor to become a better programmer I cam across this section and I'm having trouble understanding it.

Particularly the last method and how it does not enter infinite recursion if the ie_key is not found in the list.

As well as the isinstance comparision in the first method.

I understand the normal implementation is something to the effect of:  isinstance('hello', str) , but how can type() be a type? Moreover what's the point of comparing an ie object to type?

Comment: I would guess that _ies_instances is a dict, and has at some point done something like `self._ies_intances[None] = var`

Comment: It does enter infinite recursion...

Answer (score 1):

This certainly could cause infinite recursion. No updates seem to happen to `self._ies_instances` in between recursive calls, and as recursion is dependent on this case, it will continue.

Maybe this is a bug, but the code has never had a situation when `ie_key` is not in the dictionary?

As for your confusion with `type`, it's a result of [Python Metaclasses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6581949/1450189) (a great read). `type` acts both as a "function" to return the type of an object **as well as** a class to create a new type (when called with more arguments).

One reason you may want to check to see if something is an instance of `type` is to see if something is a metaclass:

```
>>> isinstance(1, type)
False
>>> isinstance("", type)
False
>>> isinstance({}, type)
False
>>> isinstance((), type)
False
>>> type(object) == type
True
>>> isinstance(object, type)
True
>>> isinstance(object(), type)
False
>>> class a(): pass
...
>>> isinstance(a, type)
False
>>> isinstance(a(), type)
False
```

As `object` is the 'base for all new style classes' ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object)), it also acts as a metaclass (as shown above).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason this avoids infinite recursion is that *it never actually recurses at all!*  Look closely:

```
def get_info_extractor(self, ie_key):
    ...
    ie = get_info_extractor(ie_key)()
```

Note that the `get_info_extractor` whose definition we're reading is a method, and it calls a non-method function that just so happens to also be named `get_info_extractor`, and so it's not calling itself, and so there's no recursion.